# undefined begin table

Tags: floats

hello I have a table looks like and gives an error not outer par mode, many thanks in advance.

```
% latex table generated in R 3.6.2 by xtable 1.8-4 package
% Sat Apr 25 14:06:59 2020
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Most Citated Countries} 
\label{tab:Most-Citated-Countries}
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrrl}
  \hline
 & Country & Articles & SCP & MCP & \%Freq & \%MCP & \%SCP & TGC & AAC \\ 
  \hline
39 & USA             & 38 & 24 & 14 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1309 &  34.45 \\ 
  5 & CHINA           & 26 & 18 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 256 &   9.85 \\ 
  38 & UNITED KINGDOM  & 15 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 199 &  13.27 \\ 
  17 & ITALY           & 9 & 7 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 55 &   6.11 \\ 
  15 & INDIA           & 8 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 103 &  12.88 \\ 
  40 & VIETNAM         & 7 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13 &   1.86 \\ 
  2 & AUSTRALIA       & 6 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 &   4.00 \\ 
  24 & NIGERIA         & 5 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 &   2.00 \\ 
  10 & FINLAND         & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 63 &  21.00 \\ 
  11 & FRANCE          & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 12 &   4.00 \\ 
  12 & GERMANY         & 3 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 271 &  90.33 \\ 
  13 & GHANA           & 3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 &   2.00 \\ 
  34 & TAIWAN          & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 56 &  18.67 \\ 
  3 & BELGIUM         & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 &   4.50 \\ 
  7 & CZECH REPUBLIC  & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 &   2.00 \\ 
  8 & DENMARK         & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 &  12.00 \\ 
  18 & JAPAN           & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19 &   9.50 \\ 
  23 & NEW ZEALAND     & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 &   5.00 \\ 
  26 & PAKISTAN        & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 &   2.00 \\ 
  29 & SINGAPORE       & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 48 &  24.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please give us a minimal (should be) working example, that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.  Right now, we can't compile this because it's missing those commands.  We could add in what's missing, but then how should we know what you need to add?  (By the way, what to xetex, tikz-styles, and xtable have to do with this?)

Comment: The table is  correct (as expected, I never seen defective  xtables) and perfectly compilable in a complete  document (e.g.,` \documentclass{article} `\begin{document} <table here> \end{document}`). What now?

Comment: `Not in outer par mode` means that you have your table in a “forbidden” place such as a `minipage`.